# How can I install OnePica ImageCDN on Magento 1.7?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

How can I install this awesome extension on my Magento? I suppose that I should install it manually, but where can I download it? And some tips for installing in my version, since it has SQL?

[OnePica Imagecdn](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/6274.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this website:

http://www.freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

and paste in the following extension key:

`magento-community/OnePica_ImageCDN`

and click `submit query`. Then click this link with the title:

`download OnePica_ImageCDN-1.0.9.tgz (492.64 KB)`

This will give your an archive file. you can open it using WinRAR. Extract the contents of the archive.

You will find the two folders inside:

`OnePica` and `modules`.

Copy `OnePica` to your webserver where your magento files are in this folder '/DOCUMENT_ROOT/app/code/community' (replace DOCUMENT_ROOT with your own path).

Then upload `modules` folder to `/DOCUMENT_ROOT/app/etc` of your magento.

Then login to your magento admin backend, flush cache. Logout and login and the module will be manually installed.

Comment: I'm going to try this, thanks!